# how to send usage metrics from spotfire to google analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, spotfire

i tried to follow the instructions on the google analytics page and also used the info on https://medium.com/all-about-analytics/integrating-google-analytics-in-tibco-spotfire-cdb91c837a7b. i dont see any data in my google analytics page. 
any inputs on how to do it. i used the below script.

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-124740775-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-XXXX');
  ga('set', 'dimension1', 'spotfire-file-name');
  ga('set', 'page', '/tab name');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

Comment: No error messages in the browser (using the F12 tooling)?

Comment: no, i don't see anything. Strangely, I saw a gtag with another tracking id! I have reached out to the team maintaining the BI platform to help on this.Thanks!